# detect Citrix ICA protocol

Tags: protocols, detect, citrix

I want to detect weather Citrix ICA protocol is running on my network or not. I don't want to hit on port because it is not a good solution.

What flags (bytes) to send to server and read its response, like detecting VNC i send some bytes to server and in response it returns me Protocol Version, so I know that VNC is running on that IP, I want such a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrix (Ica) clients can find Citrix servers on their local subnet by sending a broadcast, you could do the same. Then you can connect to any Citrix server and request a list of all Citrix servers.
[This](http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx624152) documents describes the discovery process.

Answer (score 3):

Citrix ICA is an unusual protocol in that the server talks first.

As soon as you connect to the port (default 1494), you will receive an immediate response packet containing the string "ICA" and a few other bytes.  This short packet can be repeated several times by the server.

Comment: I don't suppose the downvoter actually has anything useful to add.

Comment: I have installed XenCenter and deployed Citrix Xen Server on my Xen Blade.. Now I can use it by installing an XP VM on it but the port you mentioned (1494) is not open ??? I just want to detect Citrix ICA help me out !!! please

Comment: ICA is the protocol used by XenApp when remoting applications (and by the desktop agent in XenDesktop, though in that case the port is only open after a connection has been brokered).  Xen Server -- the hypervisor -- uses a separate protocol for management, but I've never dug into the details of that one.

Comment: Great comment but kindly help me out. I have a separate Xen Blade and on that I have installed XenServer and now I am connecting to it througn XenCenter but I want to write a software that will detect weather for e.g: client-A has a Citrix ICA protocol running?

I want to detect Citrix ICA protocol on my network and then mark those pcs that are using Citrix ICA protocol.